# unconventional structuring of sentences

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Very often we find sentences which are not structured conventionally in the subject-verb-object format.
Here is an example.

> When they arrived at the seaside, **out jumped all the children** with a shout of joy

instead of

> When they arrived at the seaside, **all the children jumped out** with a shout of joy

Are such sentences grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are grammatical. In the first the writer has foregrounded *out*, thus emphasising the children's happy exuberance.

Comment: I've *never* heard "foreground" used as a verb, but the dictionaries seem to suggest it can be so used!

Comment: I hesitated to use the past participle. _To foreground_ is perhaps the form more often found.

Comment: Noted - but I hadn't previously heard that form either. (I'm not suggesting it's not acceptable, because it's in the dictionaries - just that it's new to me.)